# Excel Conditional Formatting For Multiple Matches

Tags: excel, vba

In this Excel, I want to set a conditional formatting such as shown in these picture attached below:

[image: Screenshot]

I have set a conditional formatting at row C such as followed to highlight the cells when it is below value / refer to remark in the attached pics :

```
=IF(B3="A",13,IF(B3="B",11,IF(B3="C",9)))
```

However, when I evaluate the conditional formatting, although I set B3 to the "C", it will keep evaluate to the first condition , that is "A".

What should I do to let the conditional formatting to format to its own matches; highlight row C when it is below 13 "Product A" , highlight row C when it is below 11 "Product B" , etc.

Comment: If you have lots of Products (especially if you need an easy way to add/remove/modify Products) then you may find it easier to create a table with Product and "Highlight-when-less-than" values, and swap the `IF` block from Pᴇʜ's excellent answer out for a `VLOOKUP`

Comment: @Chronocidal , do you have an example of Vlookup ?

Comment: Lots of examples available [from Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).  You would want to look up the Product in a table, and return the "less than" value (e.g. "A" returns 13 or "C" returns 9)

Comment: @AlanQA I improved my answer by an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example select range C2:C7 and add a conditional formatting with the formula

```
=$C2<IF($B2="A",13,IF($B2="B",11,IF($B2="C",9,FALSE)))
```

---

*As Chronocidal pointed out in his comment:*
If you have not only 3 products but even more, you can use a list of products and their according *"less than"* values in combination with a VLOOKUP function:

```
=$C2<VLOOKUP($B2,$F:$G,2,FALSE)
```

Note that `$F:$G` must point to the list of products and *"less than"* values (see picture below):

[image]

This way you can easily add more products to your list without the need to adjust your formula. Also you could easily change the *"less than"* value for each product without adjusting your formula.