# Excel 2013: Conditional formatting, cross-tab requiring multiple field matches regardless of row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am attempting to implement the following formula logic:

match if (column A AND Column G from tab "2") equal (Column A AND Column G from tab "4") and from results, format column N on tab "2" to identify as a match

have reviewed several sources such as [Excel Conditional Formatting For Multiple Matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722323/excel-conditional-formatting-for-multiple-matches) however I do not appear to be advanced enough.  I cannot achieve required results.  thank you in advance for your assist.

Images of the process results follow:

[image: Sheet 1, pre]

[image: Sheet 2]

[image: Formula]

[image: Formula Cell Range]

[image: Sheet 1, post]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @JvdV, this solution worked perfectly: =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,$A1,Sheet2!B:B,$B1), or to make the workbook a little faster: =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$587,$A1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$587,$B1).

Maybe this can give you some direction:

***Sheet1*** sample data:

[image]

***Sheet2*** sample data:

[image]

Now:

- Select the range of column N you want to apply the conditional formatting on
- New conditional formatting rule > Formula:

  ```
  =AND($A1=Sheet1!$A1,$G1=Sheet1!$G1)
  ```
- Choose a format and apply, example result:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the reply!
however it appears to format all of Column N on Sheet2, considering every cell a match.  Additionally, Excel truncates it (if I return to Manage Rules) as such:
=AND($A1=$A1,$G1=$G1)

thoughts?

Comment: As you can tell by my sample it does not format the whole column. It's true though that all empty cells below your range would be matches. So hence why I said just use the rule on the range you need it to be on e.g. `$N$1:$N$3`. Conditional formatting is volatile and the more it needs to calculate the slower your workbook gets. That said, it's possible on the whole column checking for cells other than empty.

Comment: Thank you again for your interest.  I have no doubt you are right however I cannot achieve the same results and cannot figure out where I am incorrect.  I have added images to the original post, illustrating my process and the effects on a new, unformatted spreadsheet.  If you could help me see what I am missing, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'll have a look as soon as I'm behind a pc. Maybe the range to apply it to actually needs to be semi absolute?

Comment: got it.  we had accidentally swapped the sheet i wished to show results (column N) within.  Your answer, slightly modified, does the trick:  =AND($A1=Sheet2!$A1,$G1=Sheet2!$G1).  thank you.  very much appreciated.

Comment: follow-up question, if i may:  your answer works in a test file but when applied to my file it stops at the first cell.  my content and or headers contain multiple special characters.  is there something specific you might know i should watch out for?  thanks again....

Comment: If you add a link to a workbook that would represent your data I'll have a look. It's probably something rather small

Comment: @macphail, it worked for me. The second you change the range where the formula applies to the formula references will change to `=AND($A1048576=Sheet2!$A1048576,$B1048576=Sheet2!$B1048576)`. Make sure to change those back to `=AND($A1=Sheet2!$A1,$B1=Sheet2!$B1)`. If you do so the right cells will be formatted.

Comment: i apologize, but i am obviously not understanding. i cannot seem to reproduce what you describe.  If I change the range to apply, my formula stays the same 
 =AND($A1=Sheet2!$A1,$B1=Sheet2!$B1)  and the incorrectly highlighted cells do not change.  ive applied the formula to other columns but the effect is the same.  im afraid I dont understand what I could possibly be doing wrong.  thank you again for all of your help here.  you've obviously given the right answer i just need to make it work.

Comment: @macphail, please join my chat [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198387/conditional-formatting-helpout)

Comment: @macphail, you werent online when I was, not a big deal. I can't explain it directly, but if you a 100% sure you used the correct formula, you might want to try: `=AND(INDEX($A:$A,ROW())=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,ROW()),INDEX($B:$B,ROW())=INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,ROW()))`. It basically is the same formula but without the direct semi-absolute references.

Comment: So, your formula works like a champ, it seems to be my content.  I've even gone so far as to begin pasting my data into a working test file and it starts acting weird.   However, the bigger problem here is that I've realized I asked the wrong question.  Is it possible to pick out the matches from column A and Column B, regardless of row? Sheet2 is simply a sub-set of Sheet1 and therefore the rows will not match up.  Apologies, this isn't my normal toolset, im not normally this dense.  ;)

Comment: @macphail, While I only just realized the other formula should have references $A2 and $B2 since there are headers, a formula that would just check if both variables excists in sheet2 on the same row would be `=MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0)=MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$B:$B,0)`. If all this helped please don't forget to upvote the answer. I would appreciate that.

Comment: excellent response. the MATCH formula provided seems to work, however it does not  trigger on all matches correctly.  Sheet1 is ~1300 rows, Sheet2 is a subset of ~600 of these.  however when i apply the formula it only picks up ~50 or so...  I've verified I have matching entries that aren't picked up and also verified that several of the "matches" actually are not.  I'm going to create a new workbook with random data on this scale and see if I can't figure out what my mistake is.  I will update here after a little elbow grease and absolutely promote the answer.  tnx again, appreciated!

Comment: @macphail, this worked for me: `=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,$A1,Sheet2!B:B,$B1)`, or to make the workbook a little faster: `=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$587,$A1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$587,$B1)`. Didn't feel like looking into finding out why match wasn't working for you ;)

Comment: perfect.  thank you again for all the assistance.  i've updated the answer as per your suggestion.  peace!